# java instanceof and getClass() don't work as expected

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
protected LogEvent toLogEvent(LogRecord element) {
    ......
    System.out.println("element.getClass():"+element.getClass());
    System.out.println("element.getClass() == org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord.class:" + (element.getClass() == org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord.class));
    System.out.println("element instanceof org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord:" + (element instanceof org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord));
    System.out.println("element instanceof java.util.logging.LogRecord:"+(element instanceof java.util.logging.LogRecord));
    System.out.println("element.toString():"+element.toString());
```

The output is:

```
09:20:51,544 INFO  stdout element.getClass():class org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord
09:20:51,545 INFO  stdout element.getClass() ==org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord.class:false
09:20:51,547 INFO  stdout element instanceof org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord:false
09:20:51,548 INFO  stdout element instanceof java.util.logging.LogRecord:true
09:20:51,549 INFO  stdout element.toString():org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord@2657c0ad
```

`ExtLogRecord` is subclass of `LogRecord`.

My problem is:

1. In the second line why the output is `false`? clearly element is an instance of `ExtLogRecord`.
2. In the third line element `instanceof ExtLogRecord` returns `false` and in the fourth line element `instanceof LogRecord` returns `true`. So element is a `LogRecord` but it's not an `ExtLogRecord`. How is that happening?

**UPDATE:**

I have added some additional code about classloading. The output is:

```
10:32:48,372 INFO  stdout (new ExtLogRecord()) instanceof  ExtLogRecord:true
10:32:48,374 INFO  stdout new ExtLogRecord(org.jboss.logmanager.Level.ALL,"","").getClass():class org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord
10:32:48,376 INFO  stdout LogRecord.class.getClassLoader():null
10:32:48,377 INFO  stdout ExtLogRecord.class.getClassLoader():"ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.tamin.tiba.logging.jboss.handlers:main" from local module loader@416a8198(roots: D:\java\jbossas\modules)
10:32:48,378 INFO  stdout LogRecord.class.getClassLoader() == ExtLogRecord.class.getClassLoader():false
```

UPDATE 2:

Additional classloading comparisons:

```
10:43:14,113 INFO  stdout element.getClass().getClassLoader() == ExtLogRecord.class.getClassLoader():false
10:43:14,115 INFO  stdout element.getClass().getClassLoader():ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.logmanager:main" from local module loader @576fb9a5 (roots: D:\java\jbossas\modules)
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect a `LogRecord.class` to be equal to a `ExtLogRecord.class`, since the relationship is, `ExtLogRecord` is-a `LogRecord`.  Nor would I expect a `LogRecord` to be an instance of an `ExtLogRecord` (for the same reason above).

Comment: instances of `Class` are only distinct within a classloader.  Down inside the gubbins of an application server where many different apps can be running with their own class loaders, things can be weird.  (Not enough of an expert on JBoss specifically to answer with any kind of authority, sorry.)

Comment: @Makoto element's class is ExtLogRecord as line 1 and 5 indicate. so I expect line 2 and 3 to be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting those outputs for when you pass a `LogRecord` instance, and not the subclass instance. Considering the two classes, and assuming they have a 0-arg constructor, below is the result of invoking the method with 2 instances:

```
toLogEvent(new LogRecord());     // passing superclass instance
System.out.println();
toLogEvent(new ExtLogRecord());  // passing subclass instance
```

*Output:*

```
element.getClass():class LogRecord
element.getClass() == ExtLogRecord.class:false
element instanceof ExtLogRecord:false
element instanceof LogRecord:true
element.toString():LogRecord@182f0db

element.getClass():class ExtLogRecord
element.getClass() == ExtLogRecord.class:true  
element instanceof ExtLogRecord:true  
element instanceof LogRecord:true
element.toString():ExtLogRecord@192d342
```

The output is obvious. An instance of superclass is not and can not be an instance of any of its subclasses. Similarly, `LogRecord.class` cannot be equal to `ExtLogRecord.class`.

Comment: You were quicker.  +1.

Comment: +1 for the fact but if the element is of 'LogRecord' type, why 'element.getClass()' returns "class org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord"?

Comment: @mortezakhosravi `element.getClass()` returns the actual object type, and not the reference type. So, for `LogRecord element = new ExtLogRecord();`, it will give you `ExtLogRecord.class`.

Comment: I agree that in my code the actual object is of `ExtLogRecord`. So why `element instanceof ExtLogRecord` returns false?

Comment: @mortezakhosravi Are you sure you are getting `ExtLogRecord.class` for first output? B'coz your output seems to be unrealistic, unless you have 2 different ClassLoaders in scene. If it is a `ExtLogRecord.class`, then it has to be the instance of `ExtLogRecord`. That is why my output is showing.

Comment: Two different class loaders in an application? Over my head!

Comment: Yes It's exactly the output that is written to the jboss console.

Comment: @mortezakhosravi I don't have any idea about JBoss. Can you try comparing the ClassLoaders for both classes? `element.getClass().getClassLoader() == ExtLogRecord.class.getClassLoader()` and see what you get?

Comment: 10:43:14,113 INFO  stdout element.getClass().getClassLoader() ==ExtLogRecord.class.getClassLoader():false

Comment: @mortezakhosravi See? Both the classes are loaded from different ClassLoaders, and hence the result. I can't comment much on JBoss related issue, but may be you can put up some more details about how and from where that method is invoked in your question.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The problem was due to jboss classloading. I am developing a jboss module and I wasn't importing the correct dependency so jboss became weird and the `LogRecord` was being loaded in another classloader (The weird thing was that LogRecord.class.getClassLoader())

Comment: @mortezakhosravi Glad that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

- Your second line output is false since LogRecord.class is not equal
  to ExtLogRecord.class. You are passing the LogRecord instance and
  doing the equality check on its subclass
- Your third line output is false since parent class instance cannot be
  an instance of it's subclass
- Your fourth line output is true, since it's an instance of LogRecord 
  class

Hope it helps

Comment: If it is a LogRecord instance then why line 1 says element.getClass():class org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord

Comment: During runtime, the method will be invoked on the actual instance. i.e. ExtLogRecord instance is passed to the method on LogRecord argument type

Comment: Exactly.This is the dilemma since it is an `ExtLogRecord` but `element instanceof ExtLogRecord` returns false.

Comment: it really confuses me as well

Comment: we will ask Rohit Jain :)